# Laravel custom exception no directory

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel Local Filesystem.

how to throw custom exception if there no directory when using file system.
I want make new message like "no Folder found" or any custom

mkdir(): No such file or directory

I want to create custom exception when running
    Storage::disk('local')->Files('/no folder/);

or when setting custom disk
    'root' => "D:/No Folder/",

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on creating your own PHP exception with the Laravel framework:

1. Create a new file inside your app/Exceptions directory called MyCustomException.php
2. Put the PHP-tag on the top of the file: `<?php`
3. Assign the file to the namespace App\Exceptions: `namespace App\Exceptions;`
4. Create a class inside with the same name as the file (Without ".php"), extending the native Exception class: `class MyCustomException extends \Exception { }`
5. In your code where you want to throw the exception, use: `throw new App\Exceptions\MyCustomException('My own message here');`

You can read more about exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), and about extending exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php). If you want to extend an existing, built-in, exception; [here](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) is a useful page for finding which one you want to extend.

If you just want to throw a regular exception with your own message, just use `throw new \Exception('My own message here');`